# Deprecated left curly bracket in Perl regex - exactly when?

Tags: regex, perl

[`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) says this:

> (If a curly bracket occurs in any other context and does not form part
>   of a backslashed sequence like `\x{...}`, it is treated as a regular
>   character. However, a deprecation warning is raised for all such
>   occurrences, and in Perl v5.26, literal uses of a curly bracket will
>   be required to be escaped, say by preceding them with a backslash
>   (`"\{"`) or enclosing them within square brackets (`"[{]"`). This change
>   will allow for future syntax extensions (like making the lower bound
>   of a quantifier optional), and better error checking of quantifiers.)

OK, so the following prints the deprecation message.

```
perl -lE 'm/x{x}/'
```

Why doesn't the following?

```
perl -lE 'm/x({x})/'
```

e.g. in the capture group is the `{` allowed unescaped? Probably not because

```
perl -lE 'm/x(x{x})/'
```

also prints the warning.

So, what is the exact "logic"?

P.S.: I will escape every literal `{`, but am wondering about the rationale behind the above.

Comment: Seems to me it should warn too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is only emitted when the curly:

- isn't at the beginning of the pattern
- follows an alphabetic character
- is not part of a [special escape sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#All-the-sequences-and-escapes) `\b{}`, `\B{}`, `\g{}`, `\k{}`, `\N{}`, `\o{}`, `\p{}`, `\P{}`, or `\x{}`
- is not a part of a quantifier of the form `{n}`, `{n,}`, or `{n,m}`, where `n` and `m` are positive integers

See regcomp.c in the Perl source (the below is from 5.22.0):

```c
        case '{':
            /* Currently we don't warn when the lbrace is at the start
             * of a construct.  This catches it in the middle of a
             * literal string, or when its the first thing after
             * something like "\b" */
            if (! SIZE_ONLY
                && (len || (p > RExC_start && isALPHA_A(*(p -1)))))
            {
                ckWARNregdep(p + 1, "Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through");
            }
            /*FALLTHROUGH*/
        default:    /* A literal character */
          normal_default:
            if (UTF8_IS_START(*p) && UTF) {
                STRLEN numlen;
                ender = utf8n_to_uvchr((U8*)p, RExC_end - p,
                                       &numlen, UTF8_ALLOW_DEFAULT);
                p += numlen;
            }
            else
                ender = (U8) *p++;
            break;
        } /* End of switch on the literal */
```

Demo:

```
$ perl -e '/{/'    # Beginning of pattern, no warning

$ perl -e '/.{/'   # Doesn't follow alpha, no warning

$ perl -e '/x{3}/' # Valid quantifier, no warning

$ perl -e '/\x{/'  # Part of special escape sequence \x{}, different warning
Missing right brace on \x{} in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\x{ <-- HERE / at -e line 1.

$ perl -e '/x{/'   # Follows alpha, isn't a quantifier or special escape, warns
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/x{ <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
```

Comment: The comment explains it. Probably, the 5.24 will warn more. ;) Thank you for finding this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, either in the documentation or in the regex compiler. I'm not sure that it matters much though

At a wild guess, the code for raising the warning has been written for the situation where what's inside the braces doesn't look like `\d+(?:,\d+)?` but not for when there's nothing before the opening brace to quantify

For example, it accepts the braces as text and *warns* with something like `/x{4x}/` or `/x{4,x}/`, but *doesn't warn* for `/{3,4}/`, `/x({3,4})/` or `/x(a|{3,4})/`

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in which unescaped left braces weren't reported on.  It is not fixed in any stable release, but is available in the current 5.25 development series.  Stable 5.26, to be released approximately in May should have this fixed.

But the documentation has been clarified, and here it is:

> Blockquote
>   The simple rule to remember, if you want to
>            match a literal "{" character (U+007B "LEFT CURLY BRACKET") in a
>            regular expression pattern, is to escape each literal instance of it
>            in some way. Generally easiest is to precede it with a backslash, like
>            "{" or enclose it in square brackets ("[{]"). If the pattern
>            delimiters are also braces, any matching right brace ("}") should also
>            be escaped to avoid confusing the parser, for example,

```
      qr{abc\{def\}ghi}

     Forcing literal "{" characters to be escaped will enable the Perl
     language to be extended in various ways in future releases. To avoid
     needlessly breaking existing code, the restriction is is not enforced
     in contexts where there are unlikely to ever be extensions that could
     conflict with the use there of "{" as a literal.

     In this release of Perl, some literal uses of "{" are fatal, and some
     still just deprecated. This is because of an oversight: some uses of a
     literal "{" that should have raised a deprecation warning starting in
     v5.20 did not warn until v5.26. By making the already-warned uses
     fatal now, some of the planned extensions can be made to the language
     sooner.

     The contexts where no warnings or errors are raised are:

     *   as the first character in a pattern, or following "^" indicating
         to anchor the match to the beginning of a line.

     *   as the first character following a "|" indicating alternation.

     *   as the first character in a parenthesized grouping like

          /foo({bar)/
          /foo(?:{bar)/

     *   as the first character following a quantifier

          /\s*{/
```

Answer (score -1):

The logic is to issue the warning when `{...}` is in a context that could mean "match something some number of times", and not to issue it when it means something else.

Let's replace `{x}` with `{3}` and think about the regexs mean.

Your first example, `/x{3}/`  means match `x` three teams: "`xxx`"

Your last example, `/x(x{3})/`, means match `x` and then match `x` three times, capturing the string of 3 `x`'s in a group

In `/x({3})/`, the `{3}` is in a capture group by itself, and so it does mean "match something 3 times". It unambiguously means match `x` and then match the literal string `{3}`, putting it into a capture group.

Comment: But that isn't what the documentation says, which is basically that you will get a deprecation warning if you use a literal brace in a regex pattern without it being escaped

Comment: That it's a bug makes a good illustration of *why* this change is being made.

Comment: and for the `/(x){x}/` - following the logic, should emit the warning, because the `/(x){x}/` isn't an unambiguous match... but no warning...